# Add GRUB 2 menuentry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, uefi

I already install win 10 and remix os in my laptop.
remix os install grub 2 with two menu entries: windows and remix os.

then I install lubuntu from usb flash disk. after reboot there's no lubuntu menu entry in the list. I think lubuntu has own grub and different from remix os'.

I try to find where is grub location in remix os but i cannot.
there's no root access by default.

I tried to boot lubuntu by adding manual command from grub command prompt.
It works. but how to add the menu become permanently added?

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Manually editing GRUB configurations quickly leads to insanity. Fortunately, the [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) tool can help, so you may want to check it out.

Be aware, though, that with two Linux-based OSes installed, chances are you also have two GRUBs installed, and they'll both try to control the boot process. You may end up seeing which GRUB version appears at boot change from time to time. Thus, being familiar with `efibootmgr` (`man efibootmgr` or Google it to find tutorials, none of which I've yet seen is really all that good) may be helpful. Some people in multi-Linux configurations prefer to use something else, such as my own [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which is more distribution-agnostic and adapts on a boot-by-boot basis to what's available. Note, however, that if you install rEFInd, both your distributions' GRUBs may try to take control from time to time. Managing this is covered in [this page of the rEFInd documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html)